# Format current local time to 'MM/d/yyyy h:m:s:S a' format in groovy

Tags: date, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to format the current time in the format of "11/04/2016 09:48:03.5719 AM" using groovy.  I'm getting error on my second line. Any suggestion to fix it?

Note: On my first line of code it is returning the date formatted as Fri Nov 04 9:48:03 EDT 2016.

```
    def mydate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
    def date = Date.parse('EEE MMM d h:m:s z yyyy', mydate).format('MM/d/yyyy h:m:s.S a')
    log.info mydate
    log.info date
```

Comment: *I'm getting error*: **what error**? Why do you force us to guess instead of pasting it in the question? And why are you trying to parse an object of type Date? It's already a Date. There's no point parsing it.

Comment: In point of fact the reason for at least SOME error is obvious. There is no overload or mix-in of `Date.parse()` that takes a `Date` as the second argument.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet I was doing it unnecessary parse an object.  Rao code provided me what I wanted.  Thank you for your time

Comment: Thank you @BalRog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use date with formatting pattern as shown below:

```
def dateTime = new Date().format('MM/d/yyyy h:m:s.S a')
log.info "Current date and time: ${dateTime}"
```